# what is the difference between <double if> and < if... and> statements in PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm working on a coding problem.
I think the two codes are the same.
but they have different outputs.

```py
# CASE 1
if (MAP[nx][ny] == 'X'):
    if (nx, ny) not in melted:
        melted.append((nx, ny))

# CASE 2
if (MAP[nx][ny] == 'X') and ((nx, ny) not in melted):
    melted.append((nx, ny))
```

Full Code

```py
n, m = 8, 17
MAP = [['.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 
     ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 
     ['.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.'], 
     ['.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', 'L', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.'], 
     ['.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.'], 
     ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.'], 
     ['.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.'], 
     ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'L', '.', '.', '.']]

def melt():
    visited = []
    melted = []
    for r in range(n):
        for c in range(m):
            if MAP[r][c] == '.' and (r, c) not in visited:
                visited = [(r, c)]
                q = [(r, c)]
            while q:
                x, y = q.pop()
                for dx, dy in [(0,1), (1,0), (-1,0), (0, -1)]:            
                    nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
                    if nx < 0 or ny < 0 or nx >= n or ny >= m or (nx, ny) in visited:
                        continue
                    else:
                        # CASE 1
                        if (MAP[nx][ny] == 'X'):
                            if (nx, ny) not in melted:
                                melted.append((nx, ny))


                        else:
                            visited.append((nx, ny))
                            q.append((nx, ny))
                            
    print(melted)
    for x, y in melted:
        MAP[x][y] = '.'

melt()
for r in range(n):
    print(MAP[r])
```

### < outputs >

#### CASE 1.

['.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', 'L', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', '.', 'L', '.', '.', '.']

#### CASE 2

['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'L', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'L', '.', '.', '.']

Comment: the code is equivalent. It cannot have different output. Can you put the code you are running and the result of each output?

Comment: Not much difference, as in the case of `if a and b`, `b` is evaluated only if `a` is evaluated to `True`, so in both cases, `(nx, ny) not in melted` will be checked only if `MAP[nx][ny] == 'X'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not equivalent because of `else` clause.
In first case:

```
if (MAP[nx][ny] == 'X'):
    if (nx, ny) not in melted:
        melted.append((nx, ny))
else:
    other code
```

You run other code only if first condition is False, but not when second condition is false.

In second case:

```
# CASE 2
if (MAP[nx][ny] == 'X') and ((nx, ny) not in melted):
    melted.append((nx, ny))
else:
    other code
```

You run other code when either first or second if condition is False. So that is why you got different results.

Here the code that will be equivalent (just add another else clause for second if):

```
# CASE 1
                    if (MAP[nx][ny] == 'X'):
                        if (nx, ny) not in melted:
                            melted.append((nx, ny))
                        else:
                            visited.append((nx, ny))
                            q.append((nx, ny))

                    else:
                        visited.append((nx, ny))
                        q.append((nx, ny))
```